# Using AOP techniques to intercept ADO.Net

Tags: .net, ado.net, aop, castle, dynamic-proxy

I have quite a large code base using a variety of different ADO technologies (i.e. some EF and in some cases using ADO.Net directly).

I'm wondering if there is any way to globally intercept any ADO.Net calls so that I can start auditing information like, exact SQL statements that executed, time taken, results returned, etc.

The main idea being that if I can do this, I shouldn't have to change any of my existing code and that I should be able to just intercept/wrap the ADO.Net... Is this possible?

**EDIT**

Its been suggested that I look into [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp), [CciSharp](http://ccisamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CciSharp&referringTitle=Home) or [Afterthought](https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought), but how do I use one of these to get the desired results?

Comment: Seems like a redundant question. [PostSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885886/using-postsharp-to-intercept-ado-net), [AOP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870539/using-aop-techniques-to-intercept-ado-net), [CciSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885904/using-ccisharp-to-intercept-ado-net), [EF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885929/using-afterthought-to-intercept-ado-net) - **Instead, just ask the question once and cover all aspects.**

Comment: @rockinthesixstring Please dont vote me down and please remove your comment. I was asked to do this see (read the comments!) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870539/using-aop-techniques-to-intercept-ado-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. *If you're coding directly against ADO.NET types* you can't just tell DynamicProxy: "hey, put a proxy wherever I use SqlConnection in all these DLLs". DynamicProxy is a *runtime* proxy generator. It seems that you want *post-compilation* AOP, so look into [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp), [CciSharp](http://ccisamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CciSharp&referringTitle=Home) or [Afterthought](https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought) instead.

EDIT: if none of those tools are enough, you could use Mono.Cecil to directly alter your IL, but it's not easy. See for example:

- http://www.codethinked.com/static-method-interception-in-net-with-c-and-monocecil
- [How to inject call to System.Object.Equals with Mono.Cecil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372205/how-to-inject-call-to-system-object-equals-with-mono-cecil)

Comment: So would PostSharp, CciSharp or Afterthought be able to do this? i.e. even though the code says "new SqlComment()" I can proxy that...

Comment: @vdh_ant: they work by rewriting IL so in principle they can do pretty much anything.

Comment: Ok, so coming back to the question at hand how would I use any one of these to do what I need? i.e. take SqlCommand and wrap it so that I can get out the information I need...

Comment: @vdh_ant: that's another question. I'd post one question per tool, then use the answers to compare.

Answer (score 0):

**vdh_ant**:

> I'm wondering if there is any way to globally intercept any ADO.Net calls so that I can start auditing information like, exact SQL statements that executed, time taken, results returned, etc.

Why not employ the profiling tools available in your *RDBMS* instead? They are more general in that they will capture all *SQL* statements and queries regardless of specific *DB API*s. Futhermore, they provide standard performance analysis and statiscits right out-of-the box.

Another option is to write your own dummy *ADO.NET* provider, perhaps as a wrapper around the classes from `System.Data.Common` or around your specific provider if you need the DB-specific functionality. That wrapper could log the necessary information and delegate the real work to the underlying native provider.